# Alternative approach to multiple left joins

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following queries to count sales by route

```
SELECT DISTINCT q.sales_route, 
                y.yesterday, 
                t.today 
FROM   tblquotesnew q 
       left join (SELECT tblquotesnew.sales_route, 
                         Count(tblquotesnew.sales_route) AS Yesterday 
                  FROM   tblquotesnew 
                  WHERE  tblquotesnew.date_sent_to_registrations = 
                         Trunc(SYSDATE - 1) 
                         AND sales_route IS NOT NULL 
                  GROUP  BY tblquotesnew.sales_route) y 
              ON q.sales_route = y.sales_route 
       left join (SELECT tblquotesnew.sales_route, 
                         Count(tblquotesnew.sales_route) AS Today 
                  FROM   tblquotesnew 
                  WHERE  tblquotesnew.date_sent_to_registrations = 
                         Trunc(SYSDATE) 
                         AND sales_route IS NOT NULL 
                  GROUP  BY tblquotesnew.sales_route) t 
              ON q.sales_route = t.sales_route
```

I then have 6 other left joins to count current and previous week, month, and year.

This approach does work, but I was wondering if this is a more efficient (in terms of lines of code) way of pulling together this data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just need conditional aggregation:

```
select q.sales_route, 
       sum(case when q.date_sent_to_registrations = trunc(SYSDATE - 1)
                then 1 else 0
             end) as yesterday,
       sum(case when q.date_sent_to_registrations = trunc(SYSDATE)
                then 1 else 0
             end) as today
from tblquotesnew q 
group by sales_route
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use conditional aggregation

```
SELECT sales_route, 
            sum(CASE WHEN date_sent_to_registrations = Trunc(SYSDATE) 
                          AND sales_route IS NOT NULL 
                     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) today, 
            sum(CASE WHEN date_sent_to_registrations = Trunc(SYSDATE - 1) 
                          AND sales_route IS NOT NULL 
                     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) yesterday 
FROM   tblquotesnew 
GROUP BY sales_route
```

conditional aggregation leads to one sequential scan of your table which may be ok in many cases. An alternative solution is to use subqueries behind `SELECT` which may be sometimes [more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45795898/conditional-aggregation-performance). For example, if you access small subselect of data and you can create indexes to support it.